Understanding Lee's Proof of Green's Theorem (Theorem 16.17 in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds)
I have a technical question about the proof of Green's theorem in chapter 16 of Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. Recall that Stokes' theorem says that for an oriented smooth $n$-manifold ($n \geq 1$) $M$ and a compactly supported $(n-1)$-form $\omega$ on $M$,
$$
\int_{M} d\omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega.
$$
Let $D$ be a compact regular domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $P, Q$ be smooth real-valued functions on $D$. Then applying Stokes' theorem to $Pdx + Qdy$ gives
$$
\int_{D} \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right) dx \wedge dy = \int_{\partial M} Pdx + Qdy.
$$
Lee claims that we get Green's theorem, viz.,
$$
\int_{D} \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right) dx dy = \int_{\partial M} Pdx + Qdy.
$$
That is, we can "erase the wedge." This is tempting because $D$ is a domain of integration in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (as one can easily show), but the problem is that the integral $\int_D$ is in the sense of integration over a manifold with boundary (as in (16.2) in Lee's book), not integration over a domain of integration (as in p. 402 of Lee's book).
In other words, this proof of Green's theorem seems to rely on the condition that for a compact regular domain $D$, integration over $D$ as a manifold with boundary is the same as integration over $D$ as a domain of integration. Is this true?
Edit: Types of integration: I decided to add some notes here to clarify the different types of integration at play. To better distinguish between the notions of integration, I add superscripts to the integral signs.
Given a domain of integration $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose boundary has (Lebesgue) measure zero, the integral of an $n$-form $\omega = f dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n$ on $D$ is
$$
\int_D^d \omega = \int_D f dx^1 \cdots dx^n,
$$
where the right-hand side is the Riemann integral.
Given an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{H}^n$, the integral of a compactly supported $n$-form $\omega$ on $U$ is
$$
\int_U^o \omega = \int_D^d \omega,
$$
where $D$ is any domain of integration containing $\textrm{supp}~\omega$. (We can always choose $D \subseteq U$, but this works even if $D$ is not a subset of $U$, as long as we extend $\omega$ to be zero on the complement of its support.)
Given a smooth $n$-manifold $M$ with boundary and an $n$-form $\omega$ on $M$ compactly supported in a positively or negatively oriented smooth chart $(U, \varphi)$, the integral of $\omega$ over $M$ is
$$
\int_M^c \omega = \pm \int_{\varphi(U)}^o (\varphi^{-1})^* \omega,
$$
where the sign is $+$ if the chart is positively oriented and $-$ if the chart is negatively oriented.
Finally, given a smooth $n$-manifold $M$ with boundary and a compactly supported $n$-form $\omega$ on $M$, we can write $\omega$ as a finite sum $\omega = \sum_i \omega^i$ of $n$-forms, each of which is compactly supported in a single positively or negatively oriented chart (just use a partition of unity), and then we define the integral of $\omega$ over $M$ to be
$$
\int_M^m \omega = \sum_i \int_M^c \omega^i.
$$
My question is whether the following is true: for an $n$-form $\omega$ on a compact regular domain $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
\int_D^m \omega = \int_D^d \omega.
$$
It suffices to show that if $\omega$ is compactly supported in a single positively or negatively oriented smooth chart, then
$$
\int_D^c \omega = \int_D^d \omega.
$$

Isn’t this just the definition of the integral over $D$ as a manifold?

Not in Lee's book, at least. In Lee's book, in the definition of the integral over $D$ as a manifold with boundary, we reduce to the case that the integrand is compactly supported in a single positively or negatively oriented smooth chart (using a partition of unity) and then integrate the pullback of the integrand along the (inverse of the) coordinate map over a domain of integration containing the support of this pullback. The problem is that in general, a smooth chart map will not be the identity on $D$.

You raise an excellent point. Start by proving that it works out fine for the $1$-dimensional case of a closed interval. You can either ignore the boundary or work out the partition of unity argument with two charts.

Thanks. Yes, it definitely works for a closed interval. Another way to see it in the closed interval case is to parametrize by the interval as in Lee's proposition 16.8. Do you see a way to extrapolate this to the general case?

Cover $D$ by finitely many charts and use a partition of unity, as usual, to reduce to the integral of a compactly supported form on one chart. Any interior chart is obviously no problem. Now, for a boundary chart, the change of variables theorem tells you that the two integrals agree.

That's a great idea. Suppose, for simplicity, that $\omega$ is compactly supported in a positively oriented boundary chart $(U, \varphi)$ for $D$. Then $\int_D \omega = \int_{\varphi(U)} (\varphi^{-1})^* \omega$. Your argument, if I understand it correctly, is that we can now change variables, pulling back along $\varphi$. However, what change-of-variables theorem can we apply here? At first glance, we can't apply Lee's proposition 16.3 because $U$ need not be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{H}^n$.

I don’t have Lee’s books, so these references are meaningless to me. Of course the definition of a boundary chart is that $\varphi(U)$ will necessarily be open in $\Bbb H^n$.

Oh, I see. Well, in case Lee's description of integration isn't canonical, I've edited my post to describe the types of integration. Using the notation in my edits, note that in the case that $\omega$ is compactly supported in a positively oriented smooth boundary chart $(U, \varphi)$ for $D$, we have that $\int_M^m \omega = \int_M^c \omega = \int_{\varphi(U)}^o (\varphi^{-1})^* \omega$.

If $U$ were an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{H}^n$, then Lee's proposition 16.3 (one change-of-variables theorem) would show that $\int_{\varphi(U)}^o (\varphi^{-1})^* \omega = \int_U^o \varphi^* (\varphi^{-1})^* \omega = \int_U^o \omega = \int_D^d \omega$. However, while $\varphi(U)$ is certainly an open subset of $\mathbb{H}^n$, $U$ itself need not be, so this doesn't work. That's the reason I'm asking what change-of-variables theorem you have in mind.
